# EF 5 Code first Entities FirstOrDefault method returns null

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, code-first

This is an example based on Programming Code First EF.

Please look at the below classes. When the PersonRepository calls in instantiated and InsertOrUpdate method is called Null value is returned. As of i know IQuariable's FitstOrDefault should not return Null.

What is wrong here. Thanks for the help

```
    public class Person
{

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    //public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public List<Lodging> PrimaryContactFor { get; set; }
    public List<Lodging> SecondaryContactFor { get; set; }

    public PersonPhoto Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Photo Class

```
    public class PersonPhoto
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public Person PhotoOf { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext Class

```
    public class DomainContext:DbContext,IDisposable
{
    public DomainContext(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
    { 
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPhoto>()
            .HasKey(p => p.PersonID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonPhoto>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.PhotoOf)
            .WithRequiredDependent(p => p.Photo);


    }
}
```

Repository Class

```
        public class PersonRepository
    {

        public PersonRepository()
        {
        }
        public void  InsertOrUpdate()
        {
          using(        DomainContext ctx = new DomainContext())
          {
            var person= ctx.People.Include("Photo").FirstOrDefault();
            person.FirstName="Pnikey";
            if(person.Photo==null)
            {
                person.Photo= new PersonPhoto{Photo=new byte[]{0}};
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IQueryable.FirstOrDefault()` can, and indeed is designed to return null if the result is nullable.  I'm not sure why you think it can't, because that's the primary difference between `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()`

The "Default" part means that it returns the default type (ie. `default(T)`) if there is no result, and since `default(T)` for a reference type is null, that's what it returns.

If you did something like this, then it would return 0 rather than null, because int is a value type and the default value of an int is 0:

```
var x = new[] {1, 2, 3};

return x.FirstOrDefault(y => y == 4);
```

But since Person is a reference type, if there is no result, the default type is null.

Comment: I truly accept your answer. Ok But according to the example on the book Programming EntityFramework Person.FirstName = "some data"; should be executable. As its returning Null i will not be able to assign. Am i correct. Refer Programming EntityFramework CodeFirst chapter 4 (Working with One-to-One Relationships) page 87.

Comment: @Desmond - I do not own this book so I cannot reference it.  However, you should be checking for null first.  You can't assign something to an object that doesn't exist.  Are you trying to get it to create a new object if the object is not in the database?  If you have no records in your Person table, then this will fail.  You need to create a new Person object, assign the name, then add it to the Person DbSet and SaveChanges

Comment: I do understand your point but according to the book it should work. Give me some time since i have tweeted to the author of the book lets see what she say. Once i get a response i will update this. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Desmond - Turns out I actually do own this book.  The page you reference, referring to the UpdatePerson() method assumes that there is at least one person.  The very name of the method is NOT InsertOrUpdate, it's merely Update.  It's not valid to call this method if no person exists.  That's why it doesn't check for null.  The code is actually demonstrating the if (person.Photo...) part not the getting the person part.  It shouldn't probably call FirstOrDefault() without checking for null, and should call First() instead, or check for null, one of the two.